# Node.js Webdriver IO elementIdText not working properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I have the following function:

```
getElementsText() {
var textList = [];
return this.browser.elements(this.selector)
.then((res) => {
  for (var counter = 0; counter < res.value.length; counter++) {
    console.log(this.browser.elementIdText(res.value[counter].ELEMENT));
  };
});
```

}

This should print out the text of the webelements defined in my selector. If I replace the print statement with this:

```
console.log(res.value[counter].ELEMENT);
```

I get "29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35" back, which means that it is finding the elements properly.
Am I not understanding how elementIdText is used? "browser" is imported as an object from my "../setup" file, which imports webdriverio from 'webdriverio'.

Thanks

Comment: The method `elementIdText`returns a promise. So just like `elements` you need to resolve the promise with `.then` to get the text.

Comment: @FlorentB. - That depends on the version being used. In v4+, everything is synchronous, so the promises are resolved.  http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/v4.html

Comment: @garajo, he is able to call `elements(...).then`, so the execution is without doubt asynchronous. Moreover, the synchronous execution is only implemented for the `wdio` test runner and not for the standalone mode which seems to be the case here.

Comment: @FlorentB. You're right. Thanks for the pointers.